# Intellij IDEA - Unable to save plugin settings

Tags: intellij-idea, archlinux

I have the next error message ["The plugin *com.intellij.java* failed to save settings."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2For.png), when I open a file in a project,on Archlinux.
I don't have this message on Windows.

[I use the version **Intellij IDEA 2023.2.5**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNfVB.png)

[The message "Analyzing..." not disappear and the loading for autocompletion, messages helping  are not available.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RITK.png)

- Reinstall Archlinux
- Add all permission in folder **IdeaProjects**
- Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings...

Comment: Please share the logs via the menu Help > Collect logs and Diagnostic Data if possible, you may upload it to Google Drive.

Comment: [The link of logs](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pb9aD30O7zUqEAcjfUaNuCPmQJxfKHLD?usp=sharing)

Comment: My problem is solved, I corrected it by installing the **intellij-idea-ultimate-edition-jre** package (in addition to the **intellij-idea-ultimate-edition** package).

Comment: Great to hear that! I'm sorry yesterday I missed your email notification.